[Remote-SSH Bug]: Stuck in "Setting up SSH Host neuron: Copying VS Code Server to host with scp"
I'm trying to connect to the remote server via remote-ssh extension.
(0) I've written the info(Host, HostName, User) to config file
(1) Tried to connect with the remote-ssh extension via clicking on the button next to the server name("neuron")
enter image description here
(2) I typed OTP and my password as required.
And it's stuck forever in the "Copying VS Code Server to host with scp"
enter image description here
I've tried (1) setting absolute path to the /.ssh/config file (2) both values of remote.SSH.useLocalServer setting.
I'm expecting it to connect to the server after entering OTP -> password. VScode connects well to another remote server and since it's my new labtop I'm working on, I suppose it might not be a issue of crashing with "known_hosts" files, but not sure with this.

having same issue. update if you find a solution

actually i "solved" the problem by switching to an earlier version of the ssh extension (v0.113.1 was the one giving me problems and v0.112.0 is working). it would be great to have a solution that allows me to use the most up-to-date version, though

My problem was that the remote server not allowing to use visual studio code due to security issue. In the config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, AllowTcpForwarding is set to No, so I was not allowed from the start to use visual studio code. So if it worked right it shouldn't have worked with other lab members but for some reason it was only the case for me so I've been searching A LOT. I'm glad that you've solved the problem but sorry I couldn't provide you with the solution.
